# One liner to define initialized 3D matrix Mat_ in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this definition:

```
auto m = cv::Mat_<int>(3, std::array<int, 3>{8, 8, 8}.data(), 9);
```

Is there an equivalent, simpler, one line definition of `m` avoiding a cumbersome use of `std::array`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const int dims[] = {8, 8, 8};
cv::Mat m(3, dims, CV_32S, cv::Scalar(9));
```

Comment: I know this form, but I specifically asked for a one line option.

Comment: May I ask why you are focused on a one line option? One liners are not necessarily the better option. It sounded like you were more concerned about not using `std::array` which this does avoid. Also your original question before your edit had two lines with the first being a `constexpr`.

Comment: my previous answer was deleted by the mods so I hope they won't strike me down for replicating it here. have a look at OpenCV's Matx and Mat_ types. https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html#details and https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#details

Comment: @rayryeng 
1. I found the version with en extra `dim` variable harder to follow. 

2. Your answer has 3 lines, if `constexpr` is used, which is what I do in production code.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have a number of tabs with OpenCV documentation open all the time and I've seen these pages. Your links don't point to constructors suitable for 3D matrices. The answer above is an example from the documentation. I'm looking for something more concise.

Comment: So you want a one-liner because...?  You still didn't answer my question.  What is the preoccupation of being "concise"?  If what you use in production is a variant of the above, I fail to see the desire of being concise here.  Is this an academic exercise?

Comment: @rayryeng **harder to follow**, here I repeated my argument for you. It's my personal preference, yours may be different. I write this particular code for me, not for you.

Comment: ah, you actually do want a three-dimensional matrix! I don't see a constructor that's simpler.